# Replace specfic text at a line

Tags: c#, text

I want to replace a specific text at in a line at a specific part. Example text:

```
begin 355 weapon item_type=weapon
begin 356 armor item_type=armor
```

I want to replace `item_type=weapon` to `item_type=none` at line 1 by value `355` from it without replacing all `weapon` text from it and to not clean all lines and replace all with 1 line. Here is my code so far:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = File
                .ReadLines("itemdata.txt")
                .Where(x => x.Contains(itemSrchtxt.Text))
                .Take(1)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Split('\t'))
                .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                .Where(x => x.Length > 1)
                .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1]);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt");
    string content = reader.ReadLine();
    reader.Close();
    content = Regex.Replace(content, data["item_type"], textitem_type.Text);
      StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt");
    write.WriteLine(content);
    write.Close();
}
```

Here is the real line I use:

```
item_begin  questitem   783 [_alankells_receipt]    item_type=questitem
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Well, you've shown your code but you haven't mentioned what's wrong with it.

Comment: If a line cotains two same words it replaces all . I want just one to be reaplaced .

Comment: @acfrancis My question is: How to replace item_type=weapon to item_type=none at line 1 by value 355 from it without replacing all weapon text from it and to not clean all lines and replace all with 1 line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't in LINQ but LINQ looks like overkill for what you want:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt");
if (lines.Length > 0)
{
    var fields = lines[0].Split('\t');
    if (fields.Length >= 4 && fields[1] == "355" && fields[3] == "item_type=weapon")
        fields[3] = "item_type=none";
    lines[0] = string.Join("\t", fields);
}
File.WriteAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt", lines);
```

#### Complete test

Create a file called `C:\temp\t.txt`. Open it in Notepad and paste this in:

```
begin   355 weapon  item_type=weapon
begin   356 armor   item_type=armor
```

Make sure there is a tab (`\t`) and not a space between 355 and weapon and same on the second line between 356 and armor (the tab is coming out as a space when I copy-paste). Save the file and close Notepad.

Run this code (I use LinqPad):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\t.txt");
if (lines.Length > 0)
{
    var fields = lines[0].Split('\t');
    if (fields.Length >= 4 && fields[1] == "355" && fields[3] == "item_type=weapon")
        fields[3] = "item_type=none";
    lines[0] = string.Join("\t", fields);
}
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\t.txt", lines);
```

Open the file again in Notepad.

Comment: Returns error at `File.WriteAllLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\itemdata.txt");`

Comment: This is error: `No overload for method 'WriteAllLines' takes 1 arguments` .

Comment: Yes, you are correct. See updated answer. I broke it when replacing the name of my test file with your filename, just before posting. (@decPL, thanks!)

Comment: Not work. I replaced `"item_type=weapon"` with `"item_type='" + textitem_type.Text + "'"` but not work. Same made for ` "item_type=none"`

Comment: Do you need the single quotes?

Comment: No. But I used direct example without textboxes and still not work. It dose nothing text is same.

Comment: I made a example like you did and work but on my text no. Here is a line from my example:`item_begin questitem 783 [_alankells_receipt] item_type=questitem slot_bit_type={none}` and it uses tab spaces.

Comment: That line looks different from the ones in your question. You might have to adapt the code so that it works on that type of line.

Comment: @acfracis Can provide an example if posible?

Comment: In the interest of clarity, I think you should edit the question or, even better, ask a new question